# Insert starred environment or command in AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex

Simple question today – I hope the answer is equally simple.

From TextMate I am used to a keyboard shortcut that changes the current environment or command to its starred version. Is there something similar in Emacs/AUCTeX?

Comment: When you say starred command, which commands are you thinking of if you are not thinking of some environment?

Comment: Say, the `\section*{...}` command. There are some more that may be used with stars.

Comment: There does not seem to be equivalents to `LaTeX-current-environment` or `LaTeX-modify-environment` for macros so I am not sure how to add the functionality to star macros to the function I suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted [by Kilian Foth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10531256/789593) you can write a function to modify environments in such a way:

```lisp
(defun LaTeX-star-environment ()
  "Convert the current environment to its starred version."
  (interactive)
  ;; Add a star to the current environment.
  (LaTeX-modify-environment (concat (LaTeX-current-environment) "*")))
```

This function will keep adding stars (`*`) to the current environment if you repeat the command.

If you instead want a function to star the current environment if it is not already starred and to unstar it if it is already starred you can use the following function:

```lisp
(defun LaTeX-star-environment-dwim ()
  "Convert between the starred and the not starred version of the current environment."
  (interactive)
  ;; If the current environment is starred.
  (if (string-match "\*$" (LaTeX-current-environment))
      ;; Remove the star from the current environment.
      (LaTeX-modify-environment (substring (LaTeX-current-environment) 0 -1))
    ;; Else add a star to the current environment.
    (LaTeX-modify-environment (concat (LaTeX-current-environment) "*"))))
```

You can use either function by including it in your .emacs and doing <kbd>M-x</kbd> `LaTeX-star-environment` or `LaTeX-star-environment-dwim` respectively or by binding the function to a key.

Comment: Thanks! I fear the time I will have to learn basic LISP is near. Then I might be able to do that on my own...

Comment: @Thilo I have updated my answer to include a more sophisticated function and I have commented both functions to make them easier to understand if you decide to learn Lisp. It is fun to learn Lisp. I am learning Lisp by reading O'Reilly's *Learning GNU Emacs*.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently not, but it would be easy to write a tiny function to do that by using `LaTeX-current-environment` and `LaTeX-modify-environment`. (I don't have an emacs with me right now, sorry.)

Comment: Are there equivalent functions for macros? I failed to find any.